# ag-grid cell editor before open event

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid, tablecelleditor

i have a situation where i have a grid with rows. on a cell double click, cell editor is opened.
there are events arround celleditor cellEditingStarted and cellEditingStarted where you can do something if needed.
i need an event which is just before the celleditor opened.

a user double clicked the cell, need to do some thing there and the cell editor pops out after that.

is there something like that? cant find in documentation.

what i want to do is: custom cell editor pops out of the grid, and when the grid is near the bottom of screen, the cell editor is only half visible, and i made a trick, put a div under the grid and on adding a row, that div enlarges its height so it works fine, but cant make it work when you double click that cell, it doesn't scroll properly

[image]
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `agInit` lifecycle method inside the Custom Cell Editor to handle this use case as it is fired before `cellEditingStarted`:

```
export class MoodEditor implements ICellEditorAngularComp {

  agInit(params: any): void {
    console.log('agInit, handle logic here');
  }

// ...
```

You can verify this in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sU9pXE0IrRitYEOo), open the developer console to see the console log statements.

Comment: did something similar, added it into the isCancelBeforeStart(). but can be in aginit also. thanks

public isCancelBeforeStart(): boolean {
    if (this.params.node.lastChild) {
      const el = document.getElementById("target");
      if (el) {
        el.style.display = "block";
        el.scrollIntoView({ block: "end" });
      }
    }
    return false;
  }